# show percentage of duplicate questions asked

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Since there is now a duplicate for showing the percentage of answers that were marked as the accepted answer like we see for the questioner's acceptance rate, I think that we should show a percentage for the number of questions that get closed.  We could then break that down by the different close reasons.

We could expand this even further to modify the avatar to put a dunce hat as an overlay or something.

We could also show the percentage of posts, comments, etc. that are flagged for moderation attention.

Ok, I vote **NO** for all of the above...

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17130/display-number-of-duplicates-asked

Comment: Wahhh? Are you suggesting a feature request you don't even want?

Comment: Kyle I was considering my options until I clicked on the link and started laughing!

Comment: @Ian: Exactly...  Rather than vote for things that you'd like you can also vote for things you don't want!  The duplicate question on percentage for accepted answers blew my top.  I decided 1 post to knock a few options out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna have to go ahead and give a 'please-decline' answer on that one.

Excess visual clutter for minimal benefit.